# PHP Code throwing odd errors in XAMPP but not AWS

Tags: yii, amazon-web-services, xampp

I have code running on Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic Beanstalk that works great. PHP website written using the Yii framework and a MySQL (RDS) database.

I had a local instance of the code on my Widows 7 64-bit machine running through XAMPP that worked great.

Had an outside developer work on some of the pages, adding in little things here and there. All of the code works great in AWS, but now I get funky errors sometimes in my own XAMPP localhost version of the website.

Locally, I can hit my database and many pages of my website just fine. However, on some pages I see errors such as: Fatal error: Class 'COutputProcessor' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\greenlancer\protected\components\FlexDetailActiveRecord.php on line 51 (FYI - this line is the last line of the file with just a close })

And "ERROR 500: Only variables should be passed by reference"

These exact same pages work perfectly on the AWS server. Had someone bring up the point that possibly the outside developer worked on a Mac so linebreaks screwed it up somehow (I am not sure what OS he worked on)? I looked at the code and there are indeed LF instead of CRLF, but is that really going to cause an error like these? The pages that work also contain LFs and not CRLFs. How would I go about fixing this if this was the issue (keeping in mind there are lots of pages that go into building 1 HTML page due to the MVC structure, so have no idea where the actual error is being thrown from).

If it isn't this line break thing, I am at a loss as to what else to try. I have updated my XAMPP, ran through the code a zillion times, etc. Any ideas on what to look into next? What could cause code to execute perfectly on AWS yet error out a bit on XAMPP? If it were a permissions thing, or my paths set up wrong, I would think I wouldn't be able to use any of the website - but this is not the case. Help!?

Comment: What PHP version are you running in each environment, what are your error reporting settings?

Comment: Duh. It was my error reporting. I didn't realize XAMPP defaulted to STRICT when it installs PHP. Not good that my code is throwing any errors, but at least when I turn the error reporting to 0 I can see the page now. So sorry for the silly question!!!!! Thank you so much!